# Displaying expected errors to users in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, error-handling

I have found huge amounts of information (ie, [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306355)) on how to handle unexpected errors in ASP.NET, using the Page_Error and Application_Error methods as well as the customErrors directive in Web.config.

However, my question is what is the best way to handle EXPECTED errors. For example, I have a page to display a record. Each record has a specific list of users who are allowed to see it. Since many users may have the "View Records" role that are not on said list, I have to write some code on the page to filter them.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var user = Membership.GetUser();
    if (!CanUserViewThisRecord(Request["id"], user.Username)
    {
        // Display an error to the user that says,
        // "You are not allowed to view this message", and quit.
    }
    else
    {
        // Display the page.
    }
}
```

What are the best practices for handling this kind of error? I can think of a few possibilities:

1. Redirect to an error page.
2. Put a label on every page called "lblErrorText". Leave it blank unless there is an error.
3. Raise an exception and let the standard error handling deal with it.

This feels like a basic question and for that I apologize, but just about everything I've found has been in reference to unexpected exceptions. It's not that any of the above possibilities are hard to implement, but I'd like to use a standard, recommended method if possible.

**NOTE:** Thanks everyone for the answers. I want to clarify that users would NOT have the ability to click links to records they're allowed allowed to view. This question is more in the interest of being defensive. For example, since the record ID is in the URL someone could potentially enter the ID of a forbidden record in the address bar. Or User A who is allowed might e-mail a link to User B who is not. It seems I may not be using the words "exception" and "error" in the correct way, but hopefully the scenario makes sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the interest of failing gracefully, I'd go with the option to display a message on the page.

Even better is error prevention; if you know ahead of time that the user won't be able to do anything on the page, don't provide a link to it. Generally, users should only see the things that they are allowed to do.

Comment: The user won't ever see a link to a page they are not allowed to view, but the ID of the record is in the URL. I am trying to prevent a scenario where someone might manually modify the URL to contain the ID of a record they're not allowed. This is the case I'm handling here. I think what I may do is try putting an "Error text" control on the master page so I don't have to modify each page to make this work.

Comment: +1 for error prevention comment.  An 'expected error' is a bit of a contradiction, if it was expected you should have done something about it already.  IMHO manually changing a URL however is not expected.  I would treat that as an exception, handled the same as you would a user entering an non-existent ID in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, I would prefer to prevent this before it gets sent, either by disabling the functionality for these users, or catching it with javascript before the page is sent.

you would still need to check on the server that the user is allowed to make use of a control, and in such cases the suggested label would be preferable as a solution to the other 3 given.

A further solution however would be to provide a hidden value to the page which is checked by javascript within the page, generating either an alert or a more easily spotted error dialogue than a label somewhere which might be missed leading to confusion as to why nothing happened.

Edit based on questioner's comments: if modifying a number in a URL is all that is required to point to records the user is unauthorized to use, would POST perhaps be a better method to use than GET? that way the way this error is handled is less important, as no standard user would encounter it.

Answer (score 0):

Of your three options, the third would be my least favored. It's not really an exception for a user to try to view a record you told him was there.  Redirecting to an error page is more reasonable, as is the error label.  However, neither is particularly user-friendly.

I don't know how your UI is structured, but it seems to me that you shouldn't let the user try to view a record if you know that the user isn't allowed to view it.  That is, if you know that the user can't view that record, then don't give him the opportunity to click on it.  Never get to the point where you have to say, "You can't view this record."

If you can't prevent the user from trying to view the record, I think a pop-up message box would be preferable to either of your first two options.

Comment: "Exception" may not have been the best choice of words. I am not linking to forbidden pages, but the user could still edit the URL to contain a record ID they are not allowed, or they can e-mail a link to a recipient who is not allowed.

Comment: @Mike: At that point, I think a "403 Forbidden" error message is in order.  Or something similar.  "Hey!  You can't do that!"

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion this question is more methodology then tech..

i think is more right to show the error message near the object/action that cause the error.

if you send him to another page he will lost is orientation and it not be clear what cause this error.

so in my opinion is more right to put the error message in the same page.
and maybe give him the opportunity to correct..